# Why is the color of the model projected on the ground incorrect?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently studying the lighting section in three.js。
I wrote the code based on the official sample. After using a hemispherical light source, the projection color of this flamingo on the ground turned sky blue. I am very puzzled about this.
Can a friend help explain this phenomenon? How should we solve it again? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[This is the original code](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/light-wjkyf6?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90008356dd5oa9mq0%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90003356dx4p4t2gk%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90005356dsqe53rv0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90007356d0un9n931%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.48534201954397%252C46.51465798045603%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpew35g90003356dx4p4t2gk%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90003356dx4p4t2gk%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clphonj2d0003356eqq2tcw57%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A65%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A21%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A65%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A21%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FLight.vue%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clphonj2d0003356eqq2tcw57%2522%257D%252C%2522clpew35g90007356d0un9n931%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90006356dpjfmv08c%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520run%2520dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90007356d0un9n931%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90006356dpjfmv08c%2522%257D%252C%2522clpew35g90005356dsqe53rv0%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90005356dsqe53rv0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90004356djyd5a49x%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520run%2520dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpew35g90004356djyd5a49x%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)